# Copy object 'ai-is' (without animation / transforms / etc)

Tags: duplicate

I have an object that's been animated, shape keyed, transformed, etc over the course of 800 frames. Now I want to make a copy of it. But I don't want to copy all of the shape keys, keyframes or anything else. I don't care about that stuff anymore. I don't want it attached in any way. It did its job, now we're moving on to something else.

I just want to make a copy of the object (every vertex, edge and face) as it's sitting there, in that position, in the layout editor on frame 801 as a fresh, clean, unlinked, etc. object.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether "as is" means with or without the deformations due to the animation (armature, parents, shapekeys), the actions to perform are as follows:

Taking the default cube as an example, with deformations from an armature and a shapekey:

[image]

### With animation deformation

- Select mesh object, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to keep it in the same position.
- <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > convert to mesh (with is the same as going in the modifier tab and applying every modifier one by one and also applies all shape keys "as is" into the final mesh).
- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> > Clear parents keep Transformation.
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> > apply all transforms

### Without animation deformation

- Select mesh object, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to keep it in the same position.
- In modifiers tab, delete Armature Modifier
- In Mesh data tab > Shape Keys panel, use the popover menu to delete all shapekets:
  [image]
- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> > Clear parents keep Transformation.
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> > apply all transforms

Answer (score 0):

add any object you like, add this geometry nodetree:

[image]

of course, for "cube" you have to choose your object with your shape keys.

Then apply the GN modifier.

Done.